# Android - drawable-dpi images are not picking up

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm new to Android. I have an image in different size and copied to respective drawable-dpi folders. If I don't have the same image in the drawable folder, it's not getting displayed in the view. If I add the image in drawable folder, its getting displayed but not picking up based on the phone's resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place images in the `Resources/drawable` directory with Build Action: `AndroidResource`. High- and low-DPI versions of an image can also be supplied (in appropriately named Resources subdirectories such as `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, and `drawable-xhdpi`).

[image]

For mode code, you could download the source file from the GitHub for reference. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/WorkingWithImages